# How to delete a specific element from array? with String Index

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to remove/delete a specific element from an array with as index a string instead of numbers?
this is my code:

```
workout.program = new Array();
workout.program["first"] = new Array();
workout.program["first"]["time"] = 10;
workout.program["first"]["speed"] = "medium";
workout.program["first"]["slope"] = 0;
```

So it's about a 2d Array, and i want to delete everything which is under program["first"] including to delete that Array.
How to do this in pure JavaScript without JQuery?

Comment: workout.program["first"] = undefined

Comment: If you're going to be accessing elements with strings, maybe consider using a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an `object` not an `array`, so use:

```
delete workout.program.first;
```

Comment: You access arrays using a numerical index, objects by keys. `workout` is an object. `workout.program` is an object, and `workout.program.first` is an object, despite you trying to code it as an array.